# Number of paths in matrix with obstacles

Tags: c, matrix, path

so the question is about printing all the paths from top left to bottom right of a matrix. the movement allowed are down, right and diagonal. this has to be applied with obstacles, i.e if an obstacle is present then that path should not be printed. 
So I wrote this code and if run the output is

> 1 4 7 8 9
>
> 1 4 5 8 9
>
> 1 4 5 8 9
>
> 1 4 5 9
>
> 1 4 8 9
>
> 1 5 8 9
>
> 1 5 8 9
>
> 1 5 9

line 3 and 7 the last second value needs to be 6. but instead, it's 8.
Any ideas? 
TIA

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void paths(int *mat, int i, int j, int n, int *path, int val)
{
    int k,l;

    if (i == n - 1)
    {
        for(k = j; k < n; k++)
        {path[val + k - j] = *((mat + i*n) + k);}

        for(l = 0; l < val + n - j; l++)
        {if(path[l] == 0){return;}}

        for(l = 0; l < val + n - j; l++)
        {
            printf("%d ", path[l]);
        }printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    if (j == n - 1)
    {
        for(k = j; k < n; k++)
        {path[val + k - i] = *((mat + k*n) + j);}

        for(l = 0; l < val + n - j; l++)
        {if(path[l] == 0){return;}}

        for(l = 0; l < val + n - i; l++)
        {
            printf("%d ", path[l]);
        }printf("\n");

        return;
    }
    path[val] = *((mat + i*n) + j);

    paths(mat, i+1, j, n, path, val+1);
    paths(mat, i, j+1, n, path, val+1);
    paths(mat, i+1, j+1, n, path, val+1);

}

void printAll(int *mat, int n)
{
    int *path = malloc((2*n) * sizeof(int));
    paths(mat, 0, 0, n, path, 0);
}

int main()
{
    int n,i,j; 
    printf("Enter the size of the grid\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int mat[n][n];
    int count = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            mat[i][j] = count; count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Enter the grid points that are offsets\n");
    int obs[n*n][2];i=0;
    while(1 == 1)
    {
        scanf("%d%d", &obs[i][0], &obs[i][1]);
        mat[obs[i][0]][obs[i][1]] = 0;
        if(obs[i][0] == -1 || obs[i][1] == -1){break;}
        i = i + 1;
    }
    printf("The paths for the robot are\n");
    printAll(*mat, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct output, change the for loop of the `paths()` function to:

```
for(k = i; k < n; k++)
        {path[val + k - j] = *((mat + i*n) + k);}
```